# Confusing regarding the extensibility and visibility of constraints in PER

Tags: constraints, asn.1, extensibility

I got confused by the example of [X.691-0207](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.691-0207.pdf) page 49.

As per clause B.2.2.10 (Page 48): Because UNION and INTERSECTION are both commutative, the rule for the result is given only for the V first case. Where all components are V, then the normal rules of ITU-T Rec. X.680 | ISO/IEC 8824-1 apply, and these are not discussed further here. The cases where all components are I always give I, and are again not listed. The rules are:

```
V UNION I => I
V INTERSECTION I => V
-- The resulting V is just the V part of the intersection V EXCEPT I => V
-- The resulting V is just the V without the set difference I EXCEPT V => I
V, ..., I => I
I, ..., V => I
```

Following the arithmetic operation on the following example's constrains:

```
A13 ::= IA5String (SIZE(1..10, ...) ^ FROM("A".."D"))
```

yields:

```
  SIZE(1..10, ...) ^ FROM("A".."D")
= { SIZE(1..10, ...), ALL } ^ { SIZE(MIN..MAX), FROM("A".."D") }
= { SIZE(1..10, ...) ^ SIZE(MIN..MAX), ALL ^ FROM("A".."D") }
= { SIZE(1..10), FROM("A".."D") }
```

But the example said that "A13 has an extensible effective size constraint of SIZE(1..10,...)", where did the extensible come about?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you use is the equivalent of "V INTERSECTION V => V" since each of the constraints which are part of the intersection are PER visible constraints.  It should be no surprise that the result of the intersection is also PER visible.  Note that applying an INTERSECTION does not eliminate extensibility.  Rather than just looking at the informative examples in Annex B, you should look at the normative rules in section 10.3 of X.691 which explicitly defines the rules for PER visible constraints.  In particular, 10.3.9 indicates all size constraints are PER visible, and 10.3.21 indicates that when PER visible constraints that are part of an INTERSECTION, the resulting constraint is PER visible.

Comment: Thanks. I knew the resulting constraints are PER visible, but my concern is that after intersection, SIZE(1..10, ...) ^ SIZE(MIN..MAX) should be not extensible.

Comment: I think you mean section 9.3 instead 10.3.

Comment: X.691 10.3 discusses PER visibility unless you are looking at a version of the standard that is older than 2008.

Comment: Please note that INTERSECTION (which is what ^ represents) does not eliminate per visibility.  It also does not eliminate extensibility.  Doing an intersection of a size constraint with SIZE(MIN..MAX) is the equivalent of making no change to the other size constraint.  Look again at X.691 clause 10.3.21 which explains PER visibility rules for INTERSECTION.